# Not able to get children of children using StofDoctrineExtension Tree

Tags: symfony, stofdoctrineextensions

I have a database that was created dynamically just for trial purposes. I created a parent(home), set its children and then created children of those children(sub children you can say).

Now i want to only get the list of all the Sub-Children.

**My Code**

```
    $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Page');
    $nodes = $pages->getChildren();
    $parent = $nodes[0]; //get Parent node 
    $rootNodes = $parent->getChildren(); // get Children of Parent Nodes

    foreach($rootNodes as $node)
    {
        $nodes = $node->getChildren(); // get Children of Children
    }
```

Now i am returning $nodes to my view and in return i only get sub-children of only one children node instead of all the sub-children of all the children.

What mistake i am making here? Please help, Thanks !!!

Comment: The line with 'parent' is already 'children' isn't it?

Comment: $parent is actually getting the root node ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the nodes variable on each foreach.

To get all nodes you could create an array and add all subsequent nodes onto the end of that.

```
$pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Page');
$nodes = $pages->getChildren();
$parent = $nodes[0]; //get Parent node 
$children = $parent->getChildren(); // get Children of Parent Nodes

$subChildren = array();

foreach ($children as $child)
{
    $subChildren = array_merge($subChildren, $child->getChildren()->toArray());
}
```

Comment: What is $children in foreach? :/

Comment: My bad, I didn't rename `$rootNodes`. Sorted now.

Comment: Missed a bit again. Any better now?